# Angular Unit Test HostListener Functions Conditional Else part

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

How can I cover the else part of this code, here I have a host listener which show the toopt element when mouse enter and removes it on leave,  i wanted to cover the else part of this if condition in unit test.

```
@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    if (!this.tooltip) {
      this.show();
    }
  }

show() {
    this.create();
    this.setPosition();
    this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip-show');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `spy` on the component method - `spyOn(component, 'show');`

Set `component.tooltip` to some value, call the `onMouseEnter` directly and verify that `show()` wasn't called